# Perl script for combining arrays to form a structure

Tags: perl, struct

I have perl script which reads data from excel files and pushes them into an array. I have many such arrays which I want to organize them into a structure.
My arrays can be seen as:

```
@keys = {1,2,3,4};
@names = {A,B,C,D};
@var = {var1,var2,var3,var4};
@count = {c1,c2,c3,c4};
```

I want to organize them into structure as below:

```
struct 1{
    A;
    var1;
    c1;
}
struct 2{
    B;
    var2;
    c2;
}
```

Similarly, I want to organize other structs too. At the end, I want to create a array of all the structs. I want to refer the data within the structs using the reference names of that data.

It will be great if I can get help with how to reference data within the structure and also how to use them at a later time in the code.
I know that my question is abstract, but I am unable to figure out how to create/use structs in perl.

I used below link for some basic understanding of structures.
http://perldoc.perl.org/Class/Struct.html

********Edits*********

Sorry that I specify my line of codes properly. Re-writing them here:

```
my @keys = ("1","2","3","4"};
my @names = ("A","B","C","D");
my @var = ("var1","var2","var3","var4");
my @count = ("c1","c2","c3","c4");
```

Also, I want to specify the structure as below:

```
struct( 1 => {
    name => "A",  # want to iterate over the @names array to assign the values
    var => "var1",  # similarly will iterate over the @var array for each struct
    count => "c1", #similar for this one as above
});
```

I want to create a structure as above. I want to know if this is the right way of creating such structures. Later when I have an array of all such structures, I want to access the data of that struct using the struct_name and the reference name (like name, var or count).

I hope its clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unlcear what you want to achieve. Note that `{1,2,3,4}` creates a hash reference in Perl, to assign to an array, use round parentheses.

You don't need Class::Struct to build a data structure. Arrays and hashes are part of the language, see [perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata).

I had to guess hard what the output structure should be, but the following produces something similar:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @keys = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my @names = qw( A B C D );
my @var = qw( var1 var2 var3 var4 );
my @count = ('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4');

my %struct;
$struct{ shift @keys } = [ shift @names, shift @var, shift @count ]
    while @keys;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%struct;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => [
                   'D',
                   'var4',
                   'c4'
                 ],
          '1' => [
                   'A',
                   'var1',
                   'c1'
                 ],
          '2' => [
                   'B',
                   'var2',
                   'c2'
                 ],
          '3' => [
                   'C',
                   'var3',
                   'c3'
                 ]
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to create a hash and then use the data later when needed using the key and values of the hash. But I wanted to check out how to do the same using a struct. So, for that I wanted to know how to convert the array to struct and not array to hash.

Comment: Replace `$struct{ shift @keys } =` with `struct( shift @keys  =>` and add a `)` before the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a struct as in C, you'd use a hash. Other languages call it a dictionary. It's an unordered list of pairs.

```
my %thing = (
    key   => 1,
    name  => 'A',
    var   => 'var1',
    count => 'c1'
);
```

Then you can get at the pieces with, for example, `$thing{name}`.

So to convert from your lists to a hash, you want to use the same element from each list to populate the fields of your hash.

```
my %thing = (
    key   => $keys[0],
    name  => $names[0],
    var   => $vars[0],
    count => $count[0]
);
```

You want to be able to fetch things by their key. For that you need another hash which contains the things. A hash contains pairs of keys and values. The key is `$thing{key}` and the value is a reference to `%thing`.

```
$things{ $thing{key} } = \%thing;
```

If you want to get the first thing back, you use its key and get it back as a hash reference.

```
my $thing = $things{1};
print $thing->{name};
```

To do it for all your values, put that in a loop counting out the number of items. Make a `%thing` out of each column of values. And add it to the `%things` hash.

```
# This is declared outside the loop so it can be seen
# both inside and outside the loop.
my %things;

for my $idx (0..$#keys) {
    # This is declared inside the loop because we're only using
    # the variable in the loop, but the data lives on in %things.
    my %thing = (
        key   => $keys[$idx],
        name  => $names[$idx],
        var   => $vars[$idx],
        count => $count[$idx]
    );

    $things{ $thing{name} } = \%things;
}

my $thing_one = $things{1};
print $thing_one->{name};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to create a hash and then use the data later when needed using the key and values of the hash. But I wanted to check out how to do the same using a struct. So, for that I wanted to know how to convert the array to struct and not array to hash.

Comment: @V.Tej Perl doesn't have structs, unless you [drop into C and that rapidly gets messy](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) or use [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::C). Or you could muck something together with `vec` and byte arrays. [Class::Struct](http://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct) doesn't use structs, it uses hashes or arrays. It's really old and weird and should be avoided (a lot of modules that ship with Perl are like that). Instead look into an object framework like [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) or [Class::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Tiny).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look into it.